# MySql While Loop to Assign Variables

Tags: php, while-loop, variable-assignment

I'm trying to create a table that shows the outputs of a mysql query. However, if the result on a row of the query is equal to the default `null` `00:00:00` then I'd like to instead display `''`. Unfortunately, my code for whatever reason changes all of the entries to `''` if there exist any `00:00:00` in the query.  I expect the issue is with the variable not being redefined during the loop, but I am not completely sure. I appreciate any help. PHP script is as follows:

```
$table = "<ul data-role='listview' data-theme='b' id='myTabDiv'>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
  $actdep = $row['actdep'];

  if($row['actdep'] = '00:00:00'){
       $actdep = '';
  }

 $table .=  "<li><table style='table-layout: fixed; width: 100%'><tr><td>" . $actdep . "</td></tr></table></li>";

 };
$table .= "</ul>";
echo $table;
```

If you comment out the 6th line (`$actdep = '';`) then all the values show, otherwise none of them do. Only one value in the table has a time of `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using the `=` symbol in the `if` test. You should be using `==` for comparison (note the two *equals* signs.) Instead of comparing the values, you're assigning the value to the variable.

Comment: Easiest question of the day! =) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your `if` statement; rather than using the equality comparison operator, you set the value, which will also not return a boolean.

Try this, instead:

```
if($row['actdep'] == '00:00:00'){
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `==` or `===` for comparison (where the latter compares type, too, other than just interpretations of the value):

```
if($row['actdep'] == '00:00:00'){
  $actdep = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change it to

```
if($row['actdep'] == '00:00:00'){ 
     $actdep = '';
}
```

1 equals is assigning 2 equals is comparing

Answer (score 0):

i would rather place `html` code outside php

```
<ul data-role='listview' data-theme='b' id='myTabDiv'>
<?php
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
  $actdep = $row['actdep'];

  if($row['actdep'] == '00:00:00'){
?>
  <li><table style='table-layout: fixed; width: 100%'><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></li>
<?php
 } else {
 ?> 
 <li><table style='table-layout: fixed; width: 100%'><tr><td><?php echo $actdep; ?></td></tr></table></li>
<?php }
 }
 ?>
</ul>
```

I've also corrected an error with `equal symbol` 
one is used to **declare** variables, 
two is used for **equal to**, 
three is used for **different to**, (you can also `!=` for different compare) 
so you have use double to compare `==`.